# iReport pageHeader Image issue

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using iReport 3.0.0 , presently trying to make a simple change replace image inside a pageHeader with another , but the issue is the new image doesnt fit in.

1. The band height is 100
2. old image is png format, 217 x 132 ,and it is inside image element width="190" height="70" ( and this worked fine )
3. new image is png format, 192 x 130 and is inside image element width="103" height="100"

The issue is for new image there is a v small portion of the image in bottom is not showing up , i changed the height from 70 to 100 , still the same issue.

Any pointers appreciated

OLD CODE IS

```
<pageHeader>
            <band height="100"  isSplitAllowed="true" >
                <image  evaluationTime="Now" hyperlinkType="None"  hyperlinkTarget="Self" >
                    <reportElement x="0" y="12" width="190" height="70" key="image-2"/>
                    <box></box>
                    <graphicElement stretchType="NoStretch"/>
                    <imageExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_BASE_DIR}+"Old_logo.png"]]></imageExpression>
                </image>
            </band>
        </pageHeader>
```

NEW Code IS

```
<pageHeader>
    <band height="100"  isSplitAllowed="true" >
        <image  evaluationTime="Now" hyperlinkType="None"  hyperlinkTarget="Self" >
            <reportElement x="379" y="0" width="103" height="100" key="image-2"/>
            <box></box>
            <graphicElement stretchType="NoStretch"/>
            <imageExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_BASE_DIR}+"New_Logo.png"]]></imageExpression>
        </image>
```

What am i doing wrong ??

Answer (score 0):

Whats is your ireport version?

I tried it with the examples that IDE provides :

Example 1: https://gist.github.com/64fbf51838e648c28a76.git

```
<image>
    <reportElement x="2" y="0" width="118" height="132"/>
    <imageExpression><![CDATA["tree1.png"]]></imageExpression>
</image>
```

Example 2: https://gist.github.com/1a97fa35e63cabb2f8e7.git

```
<image>
    <reportElement x="275" y="0" width="300" height="64"/>
    <imageExpression><![CDATA["leaf_banner_red.png"]]></imageExpression>
</image>
```

I think is your `<box>` tag or something diferent to this examples.